# How to create Github Pull Request using curl?

Tags: bash, curl, github, github-api

I am trying to create a Github Pull Request using curl (in a bash script) and authenticating using token.

I am getting response for `curl -u my-user:token https://api.github.com/user`.
I am getting response for `curl https://api.github.com/repos/repo-owner/repo-name/pulls`

But when I try to create a pull request using the following curl command, I am getting errors:

```
curl -d '{"title":"testPR","base":"master", "head":"user-repo:master"}' https://api.github.com/repos/repo-owner/repo-name/pulls

{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#create-a-pull-request"
}
```

How to fix? What I am doing wrong?

I am not interested in creating pull request using `hub` its working fine with hub. I want to know how to use curl and do that. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're still struggling with this, make sure the token you're using has the "public_repos" permission.

Comment: Thank you @thislooksfun, apparently it was a permissions issue.

Answer (score 4):

This ([create a Pull Request](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#create-a-pull-request)) is supposed to be a POST.

```
POST /repos/:owner/:repo/pulls
```

See this [`curl` tutorial for GitHub API](https://gist.github.com/btoone/2288960):

```
curl --user "..." -X POST
```

Comment: Yes, I checked it. It also says `-d` implies that that request is POST. Even with that its not working. `curl -u "user-name" -X POST -d '{"title":"testPR","base":"master", "head":"user-repo:master"}' https://api.github.com/repos/repo-owner/repo-name/pulls`

Comment: @GauravN Your curl command does not include -u: are you unsing your token?

Comment: FYI: The GitHub API link does not work any longer. While this one might not be correct, it seems close: https://gist.github.com/btoone/2288960

Comment: @RandallBecker Thank you for your feedback. I have edited the answer accordingly.