# Can I create pull request from a fork to upstream using git bash

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I forked a project on github,and cloned my fork to my win7,set up remotes("origin" to my fork and "upstream" to the project I forked).I know to I need to push to my fork using git bash and then visit github using a browser to create a pull request so the owner can see my changes.Can I create a pull request using git bash without any plugins?

Comment: Pull Requests are GitHub entities, not Git entities, so there's no "git pr" command. You could, however, use `curl` from the command line to create a PR via GitHub's API. See details here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47467039/2422776

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you issue pull requests from the command line on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037928/can-you-issue-pull-requests-from-the-command-line-on-github)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+create+pull+request+command+line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Mureinik and @phd answered in the comments,there is no way to do it with only git bash,but can be done with GitHub's API or the [hub](https://github.com/github/hub)